# How can we troubleshoot why an add-in shows in OWA but not Outlook desktop?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We have an add-in deployed via centralized deployment that is available via OWA but not Outlook desktop. It's been 36 hours since it was deployed.

We are using M365 Apps for Enterprise, Outlook desktop version is 2202, Build 16.0.14931.20764.

I tried signing out and back in to Outlook desktop, several times, no change.

Comment: Where is you manifest? What is the min requirement set used for your add-in?

Comment: Minimum requirement set is 1.12. That highlighted my issue with the desktop version. Thanks for helping to point this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key difference between Outlook versions 2202 and OWA is support for Requirement Set 1.12. If your add-in manifest requires that, then it will not load on that older version of Office.

Documentation here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/outlook-api-requirement-sets?view=excel-js-preview&tabs=xmlmanifest

Comment: Thanks Sean! That's exactly why it's not showing up there but is on version 2208 assets we've also tested on.